# Run app deployed with XCode 7 gives a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I develop app in xcode 6.
And then device connected i run app with debug.
After i can disconnect device from xcode and again run app. And it's runs.

But today begins some problems
i run app with run button in xcode 7 -> app run normally, and work good.

After i disconnect device from my mac, and try run app by press app icon on device and got crash

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197747270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001977e516c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001976beb14 abort + 108
3   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019d56d0 0x101984000 + 333520
4   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019c955c 0x101984000 + 283996
5   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019ccf28 0x101984000 + 298792
6   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019c9640 0x101984000 + 284224
7   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019cd0e8 0x101984000 + 299240
8   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019bef50 0x101984000 + 241488
9   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib  0x00000001019c8d18 0x101984000 + 281880
10  dyld                            0x0000000120095234 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 256
11  dyld                            0x00000001200953ec ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 32
12  dyld                            0x0000000120091688 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 328
13  dyld                            0x000000012009161c ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 220
14  dyld                            0x00000001200914d8 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 136
15  dyld                            0x00000001200917a0 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 80
16  dyld                            0x0000000120086150 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 196
17  dyld                            0x00000001200898bc dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2664
18  dyld                            0x0000000120085040 _dyld_start + 64
```

How to understand what library gives a crash?

Project on ObjectiveC, use CoreData, RestKit, MagicalRecord, FacebookSDK, GoogleSDK, VKSdk, Fabric (Crashlytics and Twitter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, it's calls: "Welcome from Apple".

How you know XCode 7 give use new opportunity AddressSenitizer!

So remember DISABLE it's if you want run app without connected device to debug XCode mode.

Comment: Thanks dude, you have saved my day.