# App Crashed on start

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, crash-reports

my app crashes on start up & this happens only when I build & run from device because through Xcode it working fine.

here is my crash log. [Crash Log](http://pastie.org/10653203)

I know this happens because my app doesn't load in time & iOS kills it because it takes longer than permitted time limit.

from crash log I have understood is that its happen due to ImageLoader but I am not performing any heavy loading on start up.

Here is my Launch Method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:kUIColorWhite];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:kUIColorGreenTheme];
    NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kUIColorWhite,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];

    [self startRechabilityMonitoring];

    // Create Reports database & tables if not exist
    [[SPDBManager sharedInstance] checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [[SPDBManager sharedInstance] createTables];
    return YES;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: "through Xcode it working fine" meaning Xcode simulator?

Comment: no, when running on device through Xcode.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just Got it finally fixed.

it was Xcode 7 new feature to debug crashed called "Address Sanitizer" in edit scheme.
which should be disable when your not running through Xcode.

got my Answer from here: [ios app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663540/run-app-deployed-with-xcode-7-gives-a-crash)